# WebDriverException using headless Chrome (Python + selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

In an automated process I am using the new headless Chrome through `selenium` and in about 5-10% ratio, I'm getting a `WebDriverException`.

The exception is raised in this function, on the `Chrome` call:

```
def get_headless_browser(maximize_window=True):

    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    if maximize_window:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-fullscreen")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size={width},{height}".format(width=DEFAULT_RES[0],
                                                                            height=DEFAULT_RES[1]))
    chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_BINARY

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER,
                               chrome_options=chrome_options)  # <-- EXCEPTION RAISED HERE

    if maximize_window:
        browser.maximize_window()

    return browser
```

The exception I'm getting:

> WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception from chrome
>   not reachable   (Session info: headless chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691
>   (6ee44a7249x639z0703f292d314edf05c1531b57),platform=Linux
>   4.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)

Also, I have to mention that this code is running on a 36 core EC2 instance and this function is ran on parallel using all cores.
I have tried chopping it to 16/8 cores, same problem occurs.

Exception hierarchy:

- Error: JoblibWebDriverException

  - (sub-process traceback) WebDriverException (the exception from above)

Comment: Is there another instance of Chrome running?

Comment: Are you sure `CHROME_BINARY` is correct?

Comment: @HåkenLid it must be, he's getting the problem only 5-10% of time

Comment: @HåkenLid yes it is correct, as I said it works most of the time, but fails occasionally.
@Dundee well, I'm not sure what you are asking, but the line creating `webdriver.Chrome` objects is being executed on all of the cores...

Comment: can you add the full traceback?

Comment: It is really long, and some of it includes production code so I can't share it all, but if you need any specific part, I will supply -- in a sec I will write down the hierarchy of the exceptions

Comment: @HåkenLid the top one comes from the multiprocessing approach I guess, and the inner one from one of the parallel processes

Comment: Use PhantomJS if you need a browser headless...

Comment: @bluesummers - may it be that the script is run multiple times at once? (and thus creating multiple Chrome instances)?

Comment: The script is run once, but it spawns many processes that do the same operation using this function. @Wonka PhantomJS is not a good fit for what we are doing (I've switched from PJS to headless chrome)

Comment: Have you tried using `chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")`?

Comment: no, i have read it is unsafe, and when i explored what does it do i couldnt see how that would be related to a problem that occurs occasionally

Comment: Unsafe depends on what you are using selenium for. If you are handling sensitive data in one tab and visiting dodgy sites in another tab, you should use sandboxing.

Comment: i'll see if it's ok with out policies, might take some time for me to get it through and test it

Comment: @HåkenLid tried it with --no-sandbox, still happens :/

Comment: @sjaustirni how can it relate to running multiple chrome instances?

Comment: @mhk frankly, I am not sure today. At the time of writing the comment I was experiencing some weird issues when running multiple scripts starting a chrome instance in parallel, mainly due to the lack of RAM on my server.  I do not remember exactly why I thought this would be the case, but my guess would be `chrome not reachable` evoked in me an at the time well known memory of a crashed chrome instance due to lack of RAM.  These days I would say that the lack of RAM isn't the problem here, though.